# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'

Tags: php, pdo, oauth

Hi All I need Your Help

I got error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in /home/rails/public_html/newidenty/server.php:12 Stack trace: 
#0 /home/rails/public_html/newidenty/server.php(12): PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=ra...', 'rails_identy', 'rails_identy') 
#1 /home/rails/public_html/newidenty/registration.php(2): include('/home/rails/pub...') 
#2 {main} thrown in /home/rails/public_html/newidenty/server.php on line 12.
```

I am using 118.139.182.107/~rails/HTML/test.php Have all Infromation of PHP Version
and also showing PDO Library.

My Hosting Provide saying they install PDO in it but Getting Problem

My Code is

```
<?php
    $dsn      = 'mysql:dbname=*****;host=localhost';
    $username = '*****';
    $password = '*****';

    // error reporting (this is a demo, after all!)
    ini_set('display_errors',1);error_reporting(E_ALL);

    // Autoloading (composer is preferred, but for this example let's just do this)
    require_once('oauth2-server-php/src/OAuth2/Autoloader.php');
    OAuth2\Autoloader::register();
    $PDO = new PDO("mysql:dbname=*****;host=localhost",$username,$password);
    // $dsn is the Data Source Name for your database, for exmaple "mysql:dbname=my_oauth2_db;host=localhost"
    $storage = new OAuth2\Storage\Pdo(array('dsn' => $dsn, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));

    // Pass a storage object or array of storage objects to the OAuth2 server class
    $server = new OAuth2\Server($storage);

    // Add the "Client Credentials" grant type (it is the simplest of the grant types)
    $server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\ClientCredentials($storage));

    // Add the "Authorization Code" grant type (this is where the oauth magic happens)
    $server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\AuthorizationCode($storage));

?>
```

Please help..

Comment: @Flosculus Can u Explain it i dont know whtat is $dsn

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment because it was wrong.

Comment: I think the error means they installed PDO, but not the MySQL driver for it.

Comment: @Barmar You can check me php_info by http://118.139.182.107/~rails/HTML/test.php

Comment: In the `PDO Drivers` section it only says `sqlite`, not `mysql`.

Comment: @Barmar Thats Means PDO Only Support Sqlite not Mysql

Comment: Right, that's what it means. You need to ask the hosting provider to install the PDO MySQL driver.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to the `phpinfo()` you showed, only the PDO Sqlite driver is installed. You need to tell the hosting provider to install the PDO MySQL driver.